# Pointers and loops in C

Tags: c, pointers, loops

Please know that I'm still very new to C and pointers in general... **This is for a class so I'm not asking for explicit code**, only help *understanding* the concepts.

I'm trying to create a loop to assign random values to an int within a struct. The problem occurs when I'm assigning values to the current iteration of my pointer or array.

```
struct student{
    int id;
    int score;
};

struct student* allocate(){
    /*Allocate memory for ten students*/
    int ROSTER_SIZE = 10;
    struct student *roster = malloc(ROSTER_SIZE * sizeof(struct student));

    /*return the pointer*/
    return roster;
}

void generate(struct student* students){
    /*Generate random ID and scores for ten students, ID being between 1 and 10, scores between 0 and 100*/
    int i = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        students[i]->id = i + 1;
        students[i]->score = rand()%101;
}
```

Now, from my understanding, which is most likely incorrect, I should be able to use `students[i]` to assign values to each iteration, but VS 2010 tells me "the expression must have a pointer type." Isn't it already a pointer? It's passed into the function as a pointer, right?

Comment: "I'm not asking for explicit code, only help understanding the concepts." PLUS you haven't casted the return value of `malloc()` - this is a definitve +1.

Comment: The *content* of your array is not *pointers* to student structs; it *is* student structs. So lose the '->' usage in this case and replace with '.'.

Comment: Am I the only one bothered by the missing curly bracket? :-)

Comment: @Massimiliano nope, I as well. but the validity of his question, its presentation, and the genuine point of confusion that needed clarification seemed to take center-stage. A refreshing change of pace from the deluge of "gimme the codez plz" onslaught.

Comment: @Massimiliano yeah my apologies for not finishing that loop. I got so distracted by the error and my own confusion that I left out the last bracket. Looking back on it, it bothers the hell out of me, too.

Comment: @H2CO3 Sorry if my unfamiliarity with C bothers you. I was taught my initial classes in Java, then thrown into a course working entirely in C without any training regarding C syntax, memory management, pointers, etc.. To that point, could you expand on casting the return value of `malloc()`? I'm not sure I understand what you're getting at...

Comment: @idigyourpast It didn't bother me at all, you understood exactly the opposite of what I meant :) This question is good and you haven't made the common noob mistake with unnecessarly casting the return value of `malloc()` from `void *` to another pointer type - that's all good what you did. That's why I upvoted this question.

Comment: @idigyourpast Don't get me wrong, I just meant to joke. Your question is very well presented and surely showed effort on your side (two things that lacks in many cases, as WhozCraig pointed out)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change:

```
students[i]->id = i + 1;
students[i]->score = rand()%101;
```

to:

```
students[i].id = i + 1;
students[i].score = rand()%101;
```

Reason: `students` is a pointer to an array of `struct student`. `students[i]` is an an actual `struct student`. Note that `students[i]` is actually equivalent to `*(students + i)`.

Comment: I haven't written anything in C, but I've seen a lot of it around StackOverflow. Why does `*(students + i)` work? Why does this add four to the address instead of one?

Comment: The compiler "knows" the type of a pointer, so when it generates code for pointer arithmetic (address arithmetic) it adds the size of one element. It's much the same thing as array indexing, just different syntax.

Answer (score 5):

students is a pointer, but when you index it then you are refering to an actual instance of the structure, so hence you'll need to use `.` instead of `->` to access a field in that structure

Comment: In other words, the expression `students` has type `struct student *`, while the expression `studends[i]` has type `struct student`.

Answer (score 3):

> Isn't it (students[i]) already a pointer?

No. After you dereference it (remember: using the array subscription syntax `ptr[index]` on pointers means `*(ptr + index)`!), it will be a plain struct, for which you should use the `.` field member accessor syntax instead of the `->` which is for *pointers to structures:*

```
students[i].id = i + 1;
```

etc. should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Paul's answer will fix your problem.
But since you are asking to understand the concept...

Basically, what you did was to dynamically allocate an array of data on the heap.
Now that students is *indeed* a pointer to the array of Student on the heap.
However, when you refer to it as students[index], you are actually doing something like this

```
*(students + index)
```

You are referring to a Student instance at the location of (students + index). Note that it is already de-referenced, so you are referring to that instance directly already.
Hence, when you write students[index]->id, it is the same as

```
*(students + index)->id
```

It should be clear to you now that this is simply not the correct syntax.
You should instead write

```
students[index].id
```

which is equivalent to

```
(*(students + index)).id
```

This really means: you are incrementing the pointer called students by index * sizeof(Student) bytes in memory, and access its id field.

Comment: Throw in (students + index)->id to cover the only option left out.